# Fastest way to generate video thumbnail of particulate size by FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to generate the video thumbnail using ffmpeg but its taking even longer time to generate thumbnails than video encoding.

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -i test.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 350x200 small_thumnail.png
```

is there a fastest way to generate thumbnails ?

Answer (score 3):

You're specifying codec as motion JPEG to a raw format with the extension PNG. Those are all mismatches. Try this instead:

```
ffmpeg -ss 4 -i test.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 350x200 small_thumnail.png
```